# Hide AlertDialog in specific activity

Tags: java, android, mobile, alert

I have one Quote application. When I open the application's `MainActivity`, if there is new data updated on the server side, one `AlertDialog` is shown for going to  `SettingsActivity`. It takes some time for appear so if the app is already on `SettingsActivity`, it is still showing the `AlertDialog` to go to `SettingsActivity`.

I want to prevent the `AlertDialog` from showing in `SettingsActivity` but continue showing in other activities. My code for `AlertDialog` is below. How can I do that?

```
public class UpdatesDialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdatesDialogActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Download New Status");
        builder.setMessage("There Are New Status Arrived. Push Download Button From Settings.");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UpdatesDialogActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }

        });

        builder.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    finish();
                return false;
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for an 'instanceof' check and see if the current activity is settings or else.

```
if(activity instanceof SettingsActivity){
//don;t show dialog
}else{
//show dialog
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: hi ! I am beginner, can you please clarify more or can modify my code above and can put here ?